# Waze app not working after simple editing

Tags: waze

I've used the APK Editor (app) to make a little change in the Waze app and when I run the app it crashes again and again. How can I fix this?

Here is Log Cat:

> 05-21 21:25:14.501 12765 12765 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Signature check failed for com.waze
>
> 05-21 21:25:14.506  2518  3410 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.waze/.MainActivity

Comment: Revert your change?

Comment: but i need it. i want to bypass signature check

Answer (score -2):

you need a patch that will bypass signature check